# Windows screen resolution change: lengthen timeout

Tags: windows

Occasionally I need to change the screen resolution of the console of a Windows virtual machine using XenCenter. When you attempt this change, Windows will revert if you don't accept the changed resolution within 15 seconds of clicking 'apply.' (Normally, this is a good thing.)

The problem is that if I have a slow connection between XenCenter and the Xen hypervisor, the virtual console display may not refresh quickly enough to allow me to respond within 15 seconds. As a result, I can't change the resolution, even though the new resolution is valid.

Is there a way to increase the timeout before reverting to the original display resolution?

Comment: Which version of Windows?  Is having NO prompt for resolution changes a viable solution?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't be more detailed, because I am not in front of a windows PC.

You will notice that the prompt can be reverted by pressing enter, even if the screen is not visible. Using the arrow keys or tab or whatever you choose, practice changing the resolution, switching to the 'keep changes" button with the keyboard and pressing enter.

Then you can use this in situ, provided that keyboard input is still being accepted and the dialog box has focus

Comment: note that you can get yourself into a bit of hurt here, if you keep the changes but the resolution is not able to successfully apply